# How to install a wordpress website inside a laravel route

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, .htaccess

I'm using laravel.my server is centOS 7 and apache2.

This is my laravel routing:

```
http://example.com/{en}/{county}
```

But now I want to launch a blog page with url:

```
http://example.com/{en}/blog
```

how to add an expected url?

my blog is a wordpress.

I don't want to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is to separete wordpress and laravel folders, it can cause problem.

then you need to create a new apache conf

> sudo nano /etc/apache2/conf-available/wordpress.conf

in this conf you have to create an alias

```
Alias /blog /var/www/wordpress/

<Directory "/var/www/wordpress/">
    //here your directory conf
</Directory>
```

save it, enable it and restart apache

> sudo a2enconf wordpress.conf

> sudo systemctl reload apache2.service

now when you type http://example.com/blog you're on wordpress.

For the lang setting, i think it's better to let wordpress manage the language for the blog